# Transform variable from 'dttm' into 'POSIXCT'

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr

Working with [apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark), I have these variables with a strange format called `dttm` displayed as follows:

```
 tpep_pickup_datetime  tpep_dropoff_datetime 
               <dttm>                 <dttm>               
  2015-01-15 18:05:39    2015-01-15 18:23:42                    
  2015-01-10 19:33:38    2015-01-10 19:53:28              
  2015-01-10 19:33:38    2015-01-10 19:43:41              
  2015-01-10 19:33:39    2015-01-10 19:35:31
```

I would like to calculate the time difference in terms of seconds between `tpep_pickup_datetime` and `tpep_dropoff_datetime`.

But using `lubridate` package it doesn't work. How can I transform these variables into a `POSIXCT` format **using `dplyr`**?

When I use the following code:

```r
my_df %>% 
    mutate(diff_time = difftime(tpep_dropoff_datetime,tpep_pickup_datetime,units = "secs"))
```

I get this error:

> ```
>  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input
>  'AS' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 121)
> ```

Comment: Have you tried `difftime`  with `units ="secs"`

Comment: when i try this `my_df %>% 
  mutate(diff_time = difftime(tpep_dropoff_datetime,tpep_pickup_datetime,units = "secs"))` I get this error: `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'AS' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 121)`

Comment: @joran I thank you for your comment, I would be even more grateful if you could clarify this aspect. I'm not a spark expert, so I don't understand when I should use the collect () command and what the difference is

Comment: @joran unfortunately when I do `my_df%>% collect ()` I get an error. Probably because my data are many (over 5 GB). What do you advise me to do?

Comment: The accepted answer broke my heart. You should not do every step like that. Please try my solution, let  me know if you get an error, I will look into it to give you a somewhat reasonable answer.

Comment: Also please share your data using `dput()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  all_data <- all_data %>%
      mutate(new_pickup = as.POSIXct(tpep_pickup_datetime)) %>%
      mutate(day_pickup = as.Date(new_pickup)) %>%
      mutate(time_pickup = paste(hour(new_pickup), minute(new_pickup),second(new_pickup),sep="-")) %>%
      mutate(new_dropoff = as.POSIXct(tpep_dropoff_datetime)) %>%
      mutate(day_dropoff = as.Date(new_dropoff)) %>%
      mutate(time_dropoff = paste(hour(new_dropoff), minute(new_dropoff),second(new_dropoff),sep="-")) %>%
      mutate(trip_duration = ((hour(new_dropoff) - hour(new_pickup))*3600 + (minute(new_dropoff) - minute(new_pickup))*60 + (second(new_dropoff) - second(new_pickup))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as this [question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611777/r-and-dplyr-transforms-variable-character-into-a-time-variable) we can use `dplyr`, `lubridate::seconds_to_period` and `base::difftime` to get the output.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(dur = seconds_to_period(as.numeric(difftime(tpep_dropoff_datetime, 
                                                     tpep_pickup_datetime), 
                                                     units = "secs")))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime dur     
#>   <dttm>               <dttm>                <Period>
#> 1 2015-01-15 18:05:39  2015-01-15 18:23:42   18M 3S  
#> 2 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:53:28   19M 50S 
#> 3 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:43:41   10M 3S  
#> 4 2015-01-10 19:33:39  2015-01-10 19:35:31   1M 52S
```

If you want the output in `secs` and not `as.period`, then the code below works.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(dur = as.numeric(difftime(tpep_dropoff_datetime, 
                                                     tpep_pickup_datetime), 
                                            units = "secs"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime   dur
#>   <dttm>               <dttm>                <dbl>
#> 1 2015-01-15 18:05:39  2015-01-15 18:23:42    1083
#> 2 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:53:28    1190
#> 3 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:43:41     603
#> 4 2015-01-10 19:33:39  2015-01-10 19:35:31     112
```

#### *Data:*

```
read.table(text="tpep_pickup_datetime  tpep_dropoff_datetime 
  2015-01-15_18:05:39    2015-01-15_18:23:42                    
  2015-01-10_19:33:38    2015-01-10_19:53:28              
  2015-01-10_19:33:38    2015-01-10_19:43:41              
  2015-01-10_19:33:39    2015-01-10_19:35:31", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T) -> df1


df1 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("tpep_pickup_datetime", "tpep_dropoff_datetime"), 
            list(~as.POSIXct(.,format="%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",tz=Sys.timezone()))) %>% 
  as_tibble -> df1

df1 #just to show the data

#>   tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime
#>   <dttm>               <dttm>               
#> 1 2015-01-15 18:05:39  2015-01-15 18:23:42  
#> 2 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:53:28  
#> 3 2015-01-10 19:33:38  2015-01-10 19:43:41  
#> 4 2015-01-10 19:33:39  2015-01-10 19:35:31
```